# Installing PyTorch on PyCharmin dont work anymore

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, ide, pytorch

I cant install PyTorch in PyCharm anymore on one of my computers. PyCharm shows me some weird error messages and i was not able to solve this problem.

Im running Python 3.7 with pip 19.0.3.

Everytime i try to use commands like:

```
pip3 install torch==1.3.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

it ends up with following error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   torch==1.3.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2) No
>   matching distribution found for torch==1.3.0+cpu

If i try with this command:

```
pip3 install torch
```

this error shows up:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'

- I searched for a solution on Google all the time but did not find a solution.
- I have reinstalled PyCharm to check out if it was only a bug. The problem is still there.
- I reinstalled pip but nothing.

Can you help me?

Comment: After some hours i was able to find the real problem:

The 32 Bit version of python was installed. PyTorch need the 64 Bit Version.

Im sure this solution will help some peoples if they are going to google this problem.

Comment: i faced the same issue but python 3.7 64 BIT version solved the problem